# Microsoft.NETCore.App update to 2.1.0-rc problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am very new to .NET programming with C# and now have a problem that I cannot seem to fix no matter what I do. I would like to create an App using .NET Core and Entity Framework. I create a new application in Visual Studio (the newest version) and select C#/ASP.NET Core Web Application and then API on the second window. At the top of the window I cannot select ASP.NET Core 2.1 yet (only 2.0) but I need 2.1 to be able to use Views in EF.

I then go to NuGet package manager and see that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is at version **2.0.8**. I try and update this to `2.1.0-rc1-final` but that rolls back and says that `Microsoft.NETCore.App` does not support **2.1** -> when I try and update `Microsoft.NETCore.App` I see "*blocked by project*". To get around the .NetCore.App problem I issued this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App -Version 2.1.0-rc1
```

Now I am at **2.1.0-rc1** for `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, cool. I now try and update (using NuGet Package Manager) but still get the error message:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rc1-final is not compatible
>   with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rc1-final supports: netcoreapp2.1
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Even though `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is already at **2.1.0-rc1**. Trying to update `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` to **2.1.0.rc1-final** using the Package Manager Console command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All -Version 2.1.0-rc1-final
```

I get the same error as when trying to do it via NuGet Package Manager.

Any ideas as to how I can get this to work?

Comment: what version of visual studio are you running? Try updating to see if the dropbox includes 2.1 AFTER udpating.

Comment: Is your targetframework netcoreapp2.1 or netcoreapp2.0 in your project file? It needs to be 2.1

Comment: I am using the newest version i.e. 15.7.2.  I cannot set the project file to 2.1, only 2.0 -> that is the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your error:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rc1-final is not compatible
>   with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rc1-final supports: netcoreapp2.1
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

You need to install .NET Core 2.1 SDK. To get it go to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download), download and install the adequate package for your OS.

Comment: Just a final note - the code also runs when published to a IIS Server. Thank you @CodeNotFound

Comment: For those looking, you can find the latest SDK download here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core